# Construct on $\mathbb{R}^2$ a norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ such that the metric space ($\mathbb{R}^2 , \lVert \cdot \rVert$) is neither isometric to the

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Construct on $\mathbb{R}^2$ a norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ such that the metric
space ($\mathbb{R}^2 , \lVert \cdot \rVert$) is neither isometric to the space ($\mathbb{R}^2 , \lVert \cdot \rVert_2$), nor to the space ($\mathbb{R}^2 , \lVert \cdot \rVert_∞$).

---

Any hint ? I know that Isometry is a distance-preserving transformation between metric spaces, and I know what a metric space and norm are, but I don't really see where to start. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Pick any of the $p$ norms other than $2,\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat ... and not $1$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks. Slow today. Just to make up for my malfeasance, $\|x\| = \max_{t \in [0,1]} |x_1+tx_2|$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your help. May I ask why exactly can we take any other norm than those you said ? I'm a bit lost

Comment: @wengen Well, as Brian pointed out I was slightly wrong, $p \ne 1$ is needed as well. Proving that no isometry exists between the other norms $p \in (1,\infty) \setminus \{2\}$ is a bit of work. Mainly the $2$ norm is rotation invariant, so you can use that to show that an isometry does not exist for the others.

Comment: Do you know what is _geometrically_ special about the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\|_p=1\}$ for $p \in \{1,\infty\}$, when compared to any other $p \in (1,\infty)$? ([maybe a hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point))

Comment: @BrianMoehring If the norm gives 1, the set represents unit vectors. If p = infinity is included, that means that the maximum value in the set is 1 anyway because the infinity norm takes the absolute value of the largest member. The 1 norm is the sum of the absolute values. Does that mean there is only one member ? Do you mean that ?

Comment: No.  I meant the set of unit vectors are squares, so in particular they are the only unit "circles" out of all the $p$ norms which include open intervals of lines.  This means we can find two points with infinitely many points equidistant from them.  For all other $p$ norms, there is a unique such point, the midpoint.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant equidistant **of minimum distance** (what I wrote was false without that detail).  That is, there are two points with distance $2d >0$ such that there are infinitely many points with distance $d$ from both of them.  If $1<p<\infty$ there is only ever one such point.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $\|x\|_*$ $ = \|x\|_1 + \|x\|_\infty$. A little work shows that the unit ball in the $\|\cdot\|_*$ norm has $8$ extreme points. If $L$ is invertible, then the unit ball of the norm $x \mapsto \|Lx\|_*$ also has $8$ extreme points.

In a similar fashion, the closed unit balls of the norms $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $x \mapsto \| Lx \|_\infty$ have $4$ extreme points and similarly for
the norms $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $x \mapsto \| Lx \|_2$ have an infinite number of extreme points.

Hence $(\mathbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|_*)$ cannot be isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|_2)$ or $(\mathbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|_\infty)$.

**Addendum**:

If $C$ is a convex set, then $z \in C$ is an extreme point of $C$ **iff** $z$ is not in the relative interior of any line segment contained in $C$.

If $\alpha$ is an invertible affine map, then $z$ is an extreme point of $C$ **iff** $\alpha(z)$ is an extreme point of $\alpha(C)$.

Note that the last statement follows because $\alpha, \alpha^{-1}$ map line segments to line segments.

In particular, since an isometry is an invertible affine map, the number of extreme points of the closed unit ball is the same as the number of mapped closed unit ball.

Comment: I could just be forgetting a theorem, but is the cardinality of the extreme points of the closed unit ball really preserved by isometries?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Being an extremal point of the unit sphere is invariant under isometries

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @copper.hat   Brian Moehring and Didier. Just that I understand correctly: you use the fact that the metric spaces have different numbers of extreme points, and an isometry requires that this set of numbers is the same, which isn’t the case here, so it’s not an isometry, is that correct ?

Comment: Correct, an isometry preserves the number of extreme points of a convex set. Hence $\| \cdot\|_*$ cannot be isometric to any of the $p$ norms.

Comment: To finish answering my own question at the top of these comments, yes, I was forgetting about the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), which fills in my hole in my recognition and explains why everything here works.  Nice answer (I stumbled upon extreme points in my comment above for a much weaker reason)